# TypeScript: Can I use `never` to eliminate branches of a tagged union?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a generic utility type called `Result` for operations that might return a value or might return an error:

```js
export type Result<T, E> =
    | {ok: true, value: T}
    | {ok: false, err: E};

// Normal use
const r: Result<number, string> = performOperation1();
if (!r.ok) {
    reportError(r.err);
    return;
}
doSomething(r.values);
```

If I pass in `never` for the `E` type parameter, I know that the `ok` must be `true`, but TypeScript doesn't:

```js
const r: Result<number, number> = performOperation2();
doSomething(r.value);
```

Is there a way to get TypeScript to understand that passing in `never` here eliminates the error branch?

Note: In this tiny example, `performOperation2` could just return `number` instead of `Result`.  But in my full codebase, all of these "operation" functions conform to an interface, which returns `Result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change `Result` you can add a conditional type to not add the false branch if `never` is passed in:

```
export type Result<T, E> =
    | {ok: true, value: T}
    | ([E] extends [never] ? never : {ok: false, err: E} )

declare const r2: Result<number, never>
doSomething(r2.value);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFHAFyJgiYBG2ATgJQDeAvgFCiSwKIPYADnAZQAogwYiylAIZgAnq04dsAD2GjEUBYOyIAStgDOIADZQAPABUANIjEA+RAF4OiD4gA+iFnADWlFAMINj2AG6yZqGU1pye3ogkANpiALqI6lDYYMjGiMlg2OGMGQD8VMWMiJR+gYjAUcZhmZKUYmyITBw9HAD0fYgAciKYUYggzRzI2BBmsgKIEAjGUPyURqYWltR0jParDIREjgDcHDDASQCEDAB0AUy+7p4CmuKS0veMzOcJAlAQAwwOdOKgMDh8McSPdItFsExztNZvNFsswKt+AAmDYmcxWXb0Bj2IolBiOaboLC4AjEGFYu5w0KIjhAA)

You can also use `Exclude` to exclude the `false` branch from union:

```
declare const r2: Exclude<Result<number, never>, { ok: false}>
doSomething(r2.value);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFHAFyJgiYBG2ATgJQDeAvgFCiSwKIPYADnAZQAogwYiylAIZgAnq04dsAD2GjEUBYOyIAStgDOIADZQAPABUANIjEA+RAF4OiD4gA+iFnADWlFAMINj2AG6yZqGU1pye3r4BlMBRxmGIjAyUYogqHBwA9IWIAHIimFGIIOkcyNgQZrICiBAIxlD8lEamFpbUdIz2HQyERI4A3BwwwIgkAIQMAHQBTL7ungKa4pLSy1lMUwkCUCAMYFOcqBg4+GMky5HR2IcF9Y3N+m1gHfwATDk1I0QPVLD1zFYBvQGPYwNhwoxHPYWIhkohUmZ0mxHHV0FhcARiA8-ksnqFXkA)

This is not a direct response to your question, but might be an option if you can't change `Result`